# Pivot table in teradata sql

Tags: sql, pivot, pivot-table, teradata

I have data like this:

```
ID      Result
1       value1
2       value1
2       value2
3       value1
4       value1
4       value2
4       value3
```

How can I accomplish in teradata SQL the pivot table like in Excel.

```
ID Value1                    Value2                    ...  
1  count of Value1 for ID 1  count of Value2 for ID 1  ...
2  count of Value1 for ID 2  count of Value2 for ID 1  ...
3  ...                       ...                       ...
```

assuming that there is a large number of ID and varying number of Values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the answer and i would like to share it with you 
First of all you need to recalculate the data to know the counts for id||Value

```
CREATE TABLE myTable_count as (
SELECT ID, Result, count(1) as countOfResult
FROM myTable 
group by  ID, Result
) WITH DATA
```

Then you can do a pivot, but you have to know the names of result's

```
 SELECT ID,
 sum(CASE WHEN  Result='Value1' then countOfResult else NULL END) Value1,
 sum(CASE WHEN  Result='Value2' then countOfResult else NULL END) Value2
 FROM myTable_count
 GROUP BY ID;
```

If it help you give it a vote up.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(case when Result='Value1' then ID end) "Value1"
     , sum(case when Result='Value2' then ID end) "Value2"
FROM your_table
GROUP BY null;
```

Not much context can be added here I'm afraid, except this is the way pivots can be implemented in TD up to v15.x

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  count(
    CASE WHEN result1 = 'value1' THEN id END
  ) AS value1, 
  COUNT(
    CASE WHEN result1 = 'value2' THEN id END
  ) AS value2, 
  COUNT(
    CASE WHEN result1 = 'value3' THEN id END
  ) as value3 
FROM 
  pivot_tb1 
group by 
  1;
```

Comment: Please try to elaborate your answer a bit more. Code only answeres are not seen as high quality answer even though they might be correct. Explain what you are doing so the OP is able to follow your thoughts